# Which video formats does the vb.net web browser control support and why won't it play this video even if it works in IE?

Tags: html, vb.net, internet-explorer

I have this html in my web browser control:

```html
<html>
   <body>
      <video width="450" height="400" controls autoplay="autoplay">
         <source src="file:///C:\Rythm\*name*.mp4" type="video/mp4">
         Votre navigateur ne prend pas en charge ce format vidéo.
     </video>
   </body>
</html>
```

Of course, `*name*` is replaced with the video's actual name.
The code works in chrome and IE, but not in the web browser control.
How can I fix this?

Another solution for adding a video stored on the user's hard drive to a vb.net form would alternatively also be appreciated.

Comment: Could be due to the browser control defaulting to document mode 7.  See https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/may/21/web-browser-control-specifying-the-ie-version for explanations and possible fixes to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue might be caused by that WebBrowser in VB.NET doesn't use IE 11 by default. I try to add this line in html `<head>`, then it can work with WebBrowser in VB.NET:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Sample HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <video width="450" height="400" controls autoplay="autoplay">
        <source src="file:///C:\Rythm\*name*.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Votre navigateur ne prend pas en charge ce format vidéo.
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

Result in VB.NET Form:

[image]